# Trying to load a 3dmodel that is a .glb

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

The error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I'm trying to load a 3d model , this is my index.html and 3dmodel.js , am I doing something wrong? I also tried using the dependecncies from internet (not downloading them localy). I use it on local host via Visual Studio Code , using an extension named Live Server

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lifeboat</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo_nasa.ico">
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <div class="header-content">
      <img src="logo_nasa.png" alt="Logo" id="logo">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="virtual-library.html">Virtual Library</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="main-title">
    <h2 id="text">LIFEBOAT</h2>
    <p>Welcome to our space exploration project.</p>
    <div class="mouse"></div>
  </div>

    <!-- Container for the 3D model -->
  <div id="model-container"></div>


  <div class="content">
    <!-- Add your longer content here -->
  </div>
  
  <script src="/js/matrix_text.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="3dmodel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

3dmodel.js

```
import * as THREE from './js/three.module.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from './js/GLTFLoader.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from './js/DRACOLoader.js';

let scene, camera, renderer, model;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    // Creating the scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Setting up the camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);

    // Setting up the renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.getElementById('model-container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Adding lighting
    const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
    light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(light);

    // Adding the Draco loader
    const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
    dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('./js/'); // Adjust path as necessary

    // Adding the GLTF loader
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

    // Loading the GLB model
    loader.load('spaceship.glb', function (gltf) {
        model = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(model);
    }, undefined, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

    // Handle window resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // Optional: Rotate the model
    if (model) {
        model.rotation.y += 0.005;
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

To load the spaceship.glb under the main-title

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `spaceship.glb` file is next to the .js file and not the HTML. If you have them both in the same directory, then just put it next to them.

Then, try to change this line...

```js
//...
loader.load('spaceship.glb', function (gltf) { 
//...
```

to this line...

```js
//...
loader.load('./spaceship.glb', (gltf) => {
//...
```

What I have done here is that I have add a `./` to the start of the source link. I have, moreover, changed the function deceleration to use arrow functions. I don't exactly know why, but I have had a lot of problems with the old fashion `function` keyword once working with three.js projects.

If nothing worked, try to add a regular model, not compressed with Draco. You can find a lot of them online for free.

In case nothing worked for you, you better check on those links below and try to explain in more details what is happening. Try to upload you project to GitHub and share the repo URL. We are all here to help!

https://en.threejs-university.com/2021/08/04/loading-a-3d-glb-gltf-with-three-js-gltfloader/
https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/load-models/